# Display inputs fields from a list of field name using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have list of form field names, e.g. `list = ["orgName", "addressLine1"]` and the list can be of any length.

I tried to render form using `formik` but it throws error

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info:

```
// @flow
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import { StyledInput } from "../StyledInput";
import { Span } from "../Span";
import { Title } from "../Title";
import { SubmitButton } from "../Submit";

const OrgSignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  orgName: Yup.string().required("org name is required"),
  addressLine1: Yup.string(),
  addressLine2: Yup.string(),
  state: Yup.string(),
  city: Yup.string(),
  pin: Yup.string(),
  country: Yup.string(),
  maintainerId: Yup.string()
});

interface OrgSignupPayload {
  orgName: string;
  addressLine1?: string;
  addressLine2?: string;
  state?: string;
  city?: string;
  pin?: string;
  country?: string;
  maintainerId?: string;
}

interface IOrgSignupProps {
  title?: string;
  onSubmit: (val: OrgSignupPayload) => void;
}

export const OrgSignupForm = ({ title, onSubmit }: IOrgSignupProps) => {

  // These fields i want to render
  const fields = ["orgName", "addressLine1"];

  const initialState: OrgSignupPayload = {
    orgName: ""
  };

  return (
    <>
      {title && <Title>{title}</Title>}
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialState}
        validationSchema={OrgSignupSchema}
        onSubmit={(val: OrgSignupPayload) => {
          return onSubmit(val);
        }}
      >
        {({
          errors,
          values,
          handleSubmit,
          handleChange,
          touched,
          handleBlur
        }) => (
          <Form onSubmit={formVal => handleSubmit(formVal)}>
            {fields && fields.length
              ? fields.map((name, index) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={name}>
                    <Field name={name}>
                      {innerProps => {
                        return (
                          <>
                            <StyledInput
                              {...innerProps.field}
                              title={name}
                              type="text"
                            />
                            {innerProps.form.touched[name] &&
                              innerProps.form.errors[name] && (
                                <Span small red>
                                  {innerProps.form.errors[name]}
                                </Span>
                              )}
                          </>
                        );
                      }}
                    </Field>
                  </React.Fragment>
                ))
              : null}

            <br />
            <br />
            <SubmitButton type="submit" rounded>
              Submit
            </SubmitButton>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
```

Don't where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So on initial render you are defining `fields = ["orgName", "addressLine1"];`. I think you need to make sure `<Formik>` knows to reset the form if `initialValues` changes.

So add `<Formik enableReinitialize initialValues={initialState} ......`

Comment: Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting default values for your inputs, nor are you using the handleChange to update any values from the styled inputs.

You have to give controlled inputs a default value (i.e. `value={values.orgName}`), and make sure they have a change handler. With formik, this is as simple as `onChange={handleChange}` once you tie your input's value to its respective value in `values`. If you don't give your input a value, it's value is undefined, and react interprets this as an **uncontrolled component**.

See this github thread for specifics on your exact same issue with someone using the withFormik HOC pattern approach: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/28

I would also recommend using the withFormik HOC pattern as I've found it to be easier to debug and much less cluttered: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik

Comment: I'd like to add that, as a caveat, my answer is good advice in general, but your particular example has a lot of moving parts and stylized components. In the future, a simpler example is much easier to go through rather than a straight-forward copy/paste job.

Comment: the reason why you were able to spot it because I gave complete code. I accept there are lots of junk in the sample but it's useful sometimes.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Not sure why someone down-voted my answer. The answer works, I work with Formik/Yup everyday, and I cited my sources. But, anyway, glad I could be of some use! Have a good one.